# how could I achieve something like std::function<bool(int, int=1)> that would able to point to bool f(int)?

Tags: c++

as the question asks, I know that function pointer as written cannot be compiled. But is it possible to achieve something like  `std::function<bool(int, int=1)>` ?

Which I would like to point to both types of function `bool A(int, int)` and `bool A(int)`

A example:

```
// not compliable
std::function<bool(int, int=1)> funct_ptr;

bool A(int i, int j)
{
 return true; 
}

bool B(int i)
{
 return true; 
}

bool C(int i, int j = 1)
{
 return true; 
}

// have funct_ptr point to each function and call it
funct_ptr = A;
funct_ptr(1,1); // returns true

funct_ptr = B;
funct_ptr(1); // returns true

funct_ptr = C;
funct_ptr(1,1); // returns true
funct_ptr(1); // returns true
```

Comment: Before this can be answered, you must tell us how you intend to use a `function` variable that has one or the other of the two `A`s stored, and of which the caller of the function variable does not know which one is stored.

Comment: this could make a good question with some code added ([mcve]) and some context

Comment: Use a lambda to ignore the second parameter in the second case: `std::function<bool(int, int)> a = [](int num, int) { return foo(num);};` for `bool foo(int num);`. `std::function<bool(int, int)> b = bar;` for `bool bar(int a, int b);`

Answer (score 0):

C++ is type-safe and statically typed, unlike e.g. Python.  The allowed arguments of `func_ptr::operator()` do not depend on the runtime value of `func_ptr`, just on the compile-time type of `func_ptr`.

In your question, assigning `A`,  `B`  or `C` cannot vary the type of `func_ptr`.

But let's take back one step. You can define your *own* class which has an overloaded `operator()`, with one overload taking `(int)` and the other taking `(int,int)`. Internally, your class can contain a `std::variant< std::function<void(int)>, std::function<void(int,int)> >`.

And it's up to you how you connect the two `operator()` of your class to the two possible function pointer types internally. If your `operator()(int)` is called, but the variant contains a `std::function<void(int,int)>`, you can of course add an `1` for the extra missing argument.

I don't know how you want to handle a call to `operator()(int,int)` when the variant only contains a `std::function<void(int)>`. Throw an exception? Silently discard the extra argument? It's up to you.

Comment: Variant can be quite an overkill here. The comment suggestion of wrapping it in a lambda is likely more efficient. But maybe that's just my opinion.